# d3.js v4 force diagram update

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Trying to update a force diagram with nodes and links that already exist in the current diagram.
So for example, we have a simple diagram with two nodes A and B and a link between them "A" --> "B".

I was wondering what would be the correct way of handling if another node, exactly the same, is added.

In the fiddle I've put together and in my personal development I end up with duplicates, which I thought would be handled in

```
.data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; })
```

and the links appropriate data function 
(for example `.data(links, function(d) { return d.target; })`)

Ideally, I'm looking for "nothing to happen" when the same node/ link is added.
Hopefully, this makes sense, [please see my fiddle example here](https://jsfiddle.net/n4m1r8nb/34/)

Comment: I had this issue and I created a temp array with my node id's then checked if the id already existed before adding a new node.

Comment: That's cool for small number of updates or small number of nodes. Thanks for suggestion. Up vote for visibility

Comment: If you passed new nodes/links to update function it could even check if it exists by id before pushing, such as [this updated fiddle does for nodes](https://jsfiddle.net/n4m1r8nb/39/)

Comment: @Dan thanks for your suggestion but that is not the best solution for a big dataset with multiple updates. Also, updates might have a few nodes

Comment: If the id of each of your nodes is numeric, then you could try using the id of the node as an index to the node. e.g. var node = []; node[1] = { name: 'A' }; node[2] { name: 'B' }; This would mean the update() function would not need to search through the entire array each time as can directly reference the id. Similarly for links you would only create if the node index existed.